# How to query customField in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I'm using a GraphQL API that accepts input with the following fields:

```
UpdateClientInput { 
  customFields [CustomFieldInput!]
  firstName String
  lastName String
  id ID!
}
```

The payload returns the following fields I'm interested in:

```
UpdateClientPayload {
  cardsOnFile [CardsOnFile!]
  firstName String
  lastName String
  id ID!
  ... (many, many more fields)
}
```

I'm trying to pass in an empty array to reset these cards on file. It seems like since the cards are not a part of the accepted input that might be impossible. I'm also concerned that `customField` is some specific GraphQL code constrained only to the API I'm using.

My questions:

1. Can you pass in an empty array in GraphQL like `cardsOnFile: []`?
2. Is it possible to pass in an input for one of these fields using the `customField` attribute? If so, how?

API I'm using for reference: https://developers.joinblvd.com/graphql-admin-api/api-reference/mutations/updateClient

Comment: Before getting to an answer, note you have incorrectly copied the api schema into the OP.  According to the link, for instance, `lastName` accepts a `String` (naturally), not a string list `[String]`.  Would you mind updating the question with corrected types?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it!

Comment: #1: No. `[CardsOnFile!]` means the `cardsOnFile` field accepts a [list of non-nullable](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#lists-and-non-null) `CardsOnFile` types.  An empty array does not meet this constraint.  It is general GraphQL syntax, not specific to any particular API.  Your other questions are specific to the API you are using.